# Citation regarding a quote having to do with "truth" and what "an animal needs to believe"

Tags: truth, hegel

I'm trying to run down a quote from (I think) Hegel which I read several years ago and have not been able to find since.

The gist of it is this...

"What an animal, for the sake of its own survival, needs to believe the truth to be needn't bear any relationship to what the truth actually is."

Does this, or something close to it, ring a bell with anyone?  If so, I'd appreciate any guidance you might be able to give that would help me to run down the exact quote, its author (as I say, I think it was Hegel) and the work in which author wrote it.

Anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't help you with that quote, sorry, but this paper covers similar terrain, and you might find it useful: McKay, R. T., & Dennett, D. C. (2009). Our evolving beliefs about evolved misbelief. Behavioral and Brain Sciences, 32(6), 541–561.

Comment: Oh...thank you.  I'll take a look.

Comment: Maybe this ? George Orwell, [Looking Back on the Spanish Civil War (1943)](http://www.george-orwell.org/Looking_Back_On_The_Spanish_War/0.html): "Early in life I have noticed that no event is ever correctly
reported in a newspaper, but in Spain, for the first time, I saw
newspaper reports which did not bear any relation to the facts, not even
the relationship which is implied in an ordinary lie."

Comment: Thank you.  I don't think this is what I was looking for, but I really appreciate the time you took to try.  Notwithstanding this, in light of times in which we find ourselves living, Orwell's observation is fascinating.  Thank you for sharing it.

Comment: Not a respoonse to the request, just a reaction to this attitude (which is everywhere).  This kind of assertion offers the freedom of nihilism.  But there is actually no great freedom there to be had.  What you need to survive has to correlate with things in the environment.  It has to give answers that, although wrong in some absolute sense, make you do the right thing.  That involves bearing a relationship.  A very strong one.

Comment: This sounds like the premise of the [evolutionary argument against naturalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_argument_against_naturalism) promoted by Plantinga, who ascribes it to C.S. Lewis (who, in turn credits it to Balfour), or even to Darwin, but not to Hegel.

Comment: Nietzsche is much more likely source; the idea shows many features typical for his rhetoric and thinking. I don't see how Hegel would have used 'believe' for animals.  It is not clear how much latitude the wording of your question allows. Nietzsche's works are entirely on line & searchable - that is look for the key under the streetlight....

Comment: "Through immense periods of time, the intellect produced nothing but errors; some of them turned out to be useful and
species-preserving; those who hit upon or inherited them fought their fight for themselves and their progeny with  greater luck. Such erroneous articles of faith, which were passed on by inheritance further and further, and finally almost became part of the basic endowment of the
species, are for example..." (Nietzsche Gay Sci. 110) Is that close enough?

Comment: There are some thoughts in that direction in the Encyclopedia (around §§360 and 420f.), but it does not quite fit the bill directly.

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to respond.  After looking through your responses, I'm beginning to wonder whether the precise quote that I think I'm looking for even exists.  Insofar as the quote captures an insight that is far more clever than I could ever make up on my own, I tend to suspect that it does exist, but that I've fed you insufficient or erroneous clues to help me find it.  Although my query hasn't yielded the answer I was looking for, your thoughts and suggestions have nonetheless pointed me towards other resources that are helpful with my theme.  And for that, I thank you.

Comment: It's a pretty good line. After all this effort. I think you're entitled to claim it as your own. (McCartney spent a lot of time asking people where they'd heard the song which became 'Yesterday', because it had been living in his head for so long he didn't know whether he was its author.)
Thank me when people start quoting it back to you as one of your greatest contributions to philosophy.